# Why "Vom Arzt"? - Lokale Präpositionen

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

In my German grammar book, there's the following table:

[image]

Can somebody explain me why it's vom? Is it because Arzt is a profession or is it because it's a masculine subject?

Comment: It's because _Arzt_ is a masculine subject.

Comment: Are you wondering why it's not *von*?

Comment: Don't mind the downvote on your question. It's an excellent question.

Comment: @infinitezero It's not that excellent when it's unclear why *vom* is considered unexpected.

Comment: Ohne Transkription ist der Screenshot auch schlecht zu parsen, sei es für Indexierungsdienste, sei es für Vorlese- oder Übersetzungssoftware.

Comment: I suspected the encircled von was a giveaway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It becomes apparent when you take a look at the first row *Orte*. There the article isn't contracted (although colloquial it becomes *aus dem -> ausm*).

For people you always use von if it answers the questions "Woher?". The special case is not with Arzt but rather with *Eigennamen* such as Jana. Normally, you would also need an article there (and in some dialects, an article is put in front of a name), i.e.

> Ich komme **von** dem Arzt (short: vom)
>   Ich komme **von** der Pflege (colloquial: vonner)
>   Ich komma **von** dem Denkmal (short: vom)
>   Ich komme **von** der Jana (Hessian dialect)
>   Ich komme **von** dem Tim (Hessian dialect)
>   Ich komme **von** Ärzten (indefinite plural, no article needed)
>   Ich komme **von** den Ärzten (definite plural)

Answer (score 4):

*Arzt* is masculine. Thus it must be *von dem Arzt* same as in *aus dem Wald* or (neutr.) *aus dem Kino*.

**Vom** is short for *von dem*.

Answer (score 1):

In addition I'd like to mention that one says '*ich komme vom Arzt*' even if the doctor is female. To be more accurate, you'd rather say '*ich war bei meiner Ärztin*' than '*ich war bei der Ärztin*' because '*bei der Ärztin*' would imply that the person talked to knows who the (female) doctor is.

The reason is that *der* in '***der** Arzt*' is a generalizing article meaning *any person (even more than one) that gives medical treatment* to the speaker. So normally you would neither say '*ich komme von Ärzten*' nor '*ich komme von den Ärzten*', but '*ich komme vom Arzt*' even if you had dealings with more than one doctor. '*Ich war bei drei Ärzten*' means, that you have had three different treatments at three different dates.

Similarly, you would say '*ich war beim Biobäcker und habe dein Körnerbrot gekauft*' even if there was no baker and no man at all but just a young lady selling baked goods. And you would say '*ich war bei drei Bäckern / in drei Bäckereien, um diese verdammten Körnerbrötchen zu bekommen.*'

Comment: *Ich komme von den Ärzten* würde auch gehen, hieße aber, dass Du auf einem Konzert warst ;-)

Comment: :-) Wobei sich dann wieder die Frage stellt, ob man nicht _Den Ärzten_ mit großem D schreiben muss, bzw., darf man das überhaupt deklinieren? Scheint mir ein ungelöstes Problem zu sein. Beim Sprechen macht man da vielleicht eine kleine Pause: '_ich war bei ... deeen ... Ärzten_'. Oder wie auch immer.